# How to calculate the inverse function of $y = x + \ln(x)$?

Tags: exponentiation, inverse-function

I have had incidents in the past where my teacher gives a question on non-calculator practice exams that are impossible to solve without a calculator, where you are stuck in an endless loop of moving logs and e's around with out going anywhere.

Without a calculator I am stuck at something like $e^{x-y} = y$

However, I can't even seem to solve this with a regular calculator, and was wondering, is it even possible to solve with a calculator?

Ty.

Comment: Since $\;y=x+\log x\;$ is defined only for $\;x>0\;$ , this function is 1-1 and onto its image, which is the whole real line, and thus it has an inverse. I doubt that inverse function has an easy, elementary expression, though.

Comment: "Solve with a calculator" would be something like Newton's method.  The solution is not an "elementary function" but can be written using Lambert's W function.

Comment: What is the problem this question was based off of?  Is it possible it wasn't necessary to find the inverse function?

Answer (score 7):

As far, as I know it is not expressible in elementary functions.

Look up, for example Lambert's W-function.

You can use this.

[Lambert's function calculator](http://www.had2know.com/academics/lambert-w-function-calculator.html)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'm new to this. How can I make it comment?

Comment: You could delete it and add a comment to the question, but seeing as how the upvotes are raining in, I'd suggest you edit your answer to be more detailed (for instance, giving the solution, and addressing the calculator-part of the question). Welcome to the site, btw! :)

Comment: Thank you. I just searched and added. I'm sorry again. Next time I will be more accurate.

Comment: I would say this constitutes an answer.

Answer (score 5):

$$e^y=e^{x+\ln x}$$

$$e^y=e^x\cdot e^{\ln x}=xe^x$$

The inverse of $xe^x$ is Lambert's W-function

Then

$$x=W(e^y)$$

Comment: does the W() affect the e^y? or is it just e^y?

Answer (score 2):

As it was already pointed out
$$
y = x + \ln(x) \iff e^y = x e^x
$$
which is the inverse of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which is known to be non-elementary.

So you would need to go through some approximation with your calculator.

E.g. if you got some value $y$ you could try [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find a root of the equation
$$
f(x) = x e^x - e^y
$$
which turns into the iteration
\begin{align}
x_{n+1} 
&= x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} \\
&= x_n - \frac{x_n e^{x_n} - e^y}{e^{x_n} + x_n e^{x_n}} \\
&= x_n - \frac{x_n e^{x_n} - e^y}{x_n e^{x_n} + e^{x_n}} \\
\end{align}